# labeling multiple revisions in svn under single label for identification

Tags: svn, label, tortoisesvn

Is there a way to tag multiple code check-ins(revisions) under same heading/label in svn. For e.g. i have 2 code check-ins(revision no's) 1023 and 1028 and I want to label both under single heading for my reference that they are related to xyz issue. I want to identify using some label text that these 2 code revisions/modifications are related to a same issue.

Comment: I am using tortoise SVN client to access code repository. Step to do this using SVN tortoise would be good for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you could do

```
$ svn propset issue --revprop -r 1023 xyz
$ svn propset issue --revprop -r 1028 xyz
```

I'm afraid, this won't work "backwards"—in the sense I see no way to search for a revprop named "xyz" and get those two revisions back.

Looks like if you'd need that, you'd need to setup something different—like a special remote folder, say, "^/issues", coupled with creative copying,
like in

```
$ svn cp ^/trunk@1023 ^/issues/xyz
$ svn cp ^/trunk@1028 ^/issues/xyz
```

Or having a (versioned) property on your root folder or a branch
and updating it like a key/value text file:

```
xyz: 1023 1028
…
```

Comment: @kortix Thanks for your answer, I am using tortoise svn client, can we do the same using tortoise svn utility instead of doing it command line.

Comment: @Viki, please google yourself. It appears the answer is [yes](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html#tsvn-dug-propertypage-editors). BTW that page has a section titled "Issue Tracker Integration"—may be this would be of interest to you as well.